# Firebase - error when trying to get items from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using Firestore/Firebase and I am trying to grab the users from my firebase database, however, I am getting this error and I'm not sure why.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (firestore.js:28)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:4697)
    at new AngularFirestore (firestore.js:26)
    at _createClass (core.js:10901)
    ...
```

The code in my service in the constructor to get the collection of tutors (using a Tutor model):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Tutor } from '../_model/tutor.model';


@Injectable()
export class FirestoreService {
  tutorsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Tutor>;
  tutorDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Tutor>;
  tutors: Observable<Tutor[]>;
  tutor: Observable<Tutor>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.tutorsCollection = this.afs.collection('tutors', 
    ref => ref.orderBy('name', 'asc'));
  }
}
```

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.8",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.8.1-next",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-vertical-tabs": "^1.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "countup.js-angular2": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.10",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

My environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: ...,
    authDomain: ...,
    databaseURL: ...,
    projectId: ...,
    storageBucket: ...,
    messagingSenderId: ...
  }
};
```

I know there are some breakages with Firebase updates and some compatibility issues, but, not sure where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your rxjs version to 6 this is most likely your solution.

Here is a link with the same issue and my solution: [Object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528351/runtime-error-object-is-not-a-function-ionic-firebase-angular/50528690#50528690)

You need to update rxjs version because angularfire2 requires version 6 from higher than rc7 or maybe even earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```