# Was there a recent breaking change in RXJS?

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2, angular6, rxjs6

I have the following code in Angular 6, that worked fine before.

```
 getNavigation(db): any {
    return db.list('/pages', ref => {
        let query = ref.limitToLast(100).orderByChild('sortOrder');
        return query;
    }).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(change => ({key: change.payload.key, ...change.payload.val()}));
    });
}
```

Suddenly, with some recent library update (rxjs ??)  it throws an error?   What syntax has changed that suddenly broke my code?

> ERROR TypeError: db.list(...).snapshotChanges(...).map is not a
>   function
>       at NavigationComponent.push../src/app/navigation.component.ts.NavigationComponent.getNavigation

Or more importantly, how do I fix it? :-(

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @DiabolicWords Updated with the error.

Comment: "with some recent library update" what did you change? What libraries did you update?

Comment: What version were you using previously and what version are you using now?

Comment: I was using Angular 6.0.0 and rxjs 6.1.0, and upgraded to Angular 6.0.3 and rxjs 6.2.0.

Comment: All changes are in a file called CHANGELOG. Why not read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally figured this out.

Here is the working code for anyone who runs into a similar problem:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable}  from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LogoComponent } from './logo.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html'
})


export class NavigationComponent {
    items: Observable<any[]>;
    childItems: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.items = this.getNavigation(db);
        this.childItems = this.getNavigation(db);
    }

    getNavigation(db: AngularFireDatabase): any {
        return db.list('/pages', ref => {
            let query = ref.limitToLast(100).orderByChild('sortOrder');
            return query;
        }).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(pages => {
                return pages.map(p => ({ key: p.key, ...p.payload.val() }));
            })
        );
    }
}
```

To get past the typescript error, I had to type the `db` parameter of `getNavigation`.

Then I had to remove the unnecessary subscribe function that was shown in both the feedback to this question and in AngularFire's migration documents.   While this might be necessary in some use cases, it was not in mine.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the map operator:

```
getNavigation(db): any {
    return db.list('/pages', ref => {
        let query = ref.limitToLast(100).orderByChild('sortOrder');
        return query;
    }).snapshotChanges().pipe(
map(changes => {
        return changes.map(change => ({key: change.payload.key, ...change.payload.val()}));
    }));
}
```

Also make sure you import `map` in the correct way:

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}' even with the import.   Note this is on the `return changes.map(change =>` line

Comment: import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: changes is not an Observable, and why try to map it?

Comment: If the type of 'changes' is an Array only you can use the map (Array.prototype.map), otherwise you should remove that map.

Comment: angular fire 2 is espacalliy only compatible with rxjs 6 not lower. So if you have there a problem update your rxjs version to 6

Comment: @Benjamin Schröder Please provide any evidence (such as links to official docs etc.) for your claim regarding AngularFire2 and RxJS compatibility.

Comment: here: [GitHub discussion of RXJS version](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1668) Here: [Stack overflow discussion of Object is not a function with RXJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) Here: [My own answer to one of the problems regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528351/runtime-error-object-is-not-a-function-ionic-firebase-angular/50528690#50528690) hi hope this helps.

Comment: Well this is running AngularFire 2 6.0.3 and rxjs 6.2.0 so that is not the problem.