# Why I get a "Function Expected" Error when using NgFor, accessing Firebase, Ionic3 and AngularFire

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2, ngfor

I'm using Ionic3 and Angularfire2 to access a Firebase Database. I create a ".ts" file called "Service" in order to export a function called "gelAll" to get a list from a table called 'cores' in Firebase.

```
 constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {  }
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('cores').valueChanges();
  }`
```

After that, I import getAll class to other ".ts" file in order to use the list:

```
export class HomePage {

  private listaCores;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dbService: FirebaseServiceProvider ) {
  this.listaCores = this.dbService.getAll();
  }
```

Everything works fine at this point, but when I try to show the 'listaCores' in the screen using a simple ngFor I have a "Function Expected" error...

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of listaCores|async">
      {{c.descCor}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Any idea why does it happen? Maybe a data problem in the Firebase?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a runtime problem, the loop ngFor is trying to access the variable before a value was set, instead of call the function in the constructor try this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.listaCores = this.dbService.getAll();
}
```

ionViewDidLoad is part of the view lifecycle

Comment: Hey man, it is a run time error indeed and i appreciate your suggestion but it didn't work...  I have found a topic that is very similar to mine, but the solution didn't work for me either, (i had to update the rxjs though).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528351/runtime-error-object-is-not-a-function-ionic-firebase-angular

Comment: Actually I installed the rxjs 6.x and it worked! Thanks Anway!